# Is there any way to install rpostgis through conda?

Tags: r, anaconda, postgis

How to use conda install to install package rpostgis in R environment? But I can't find the package.

If I use install.packages to install, I'll receive the following errors:

```
`Error: object 'blocks' is not exported by 'namespace:terra'
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'rpostgis'`
```

I think installs in R cannot figure out the dependency well. so I want to use conda instead. but the problem is that I can't find the rpostgis package.